# Why we don't care about minimizing Push Down Automata & Turing Machines?

Tags: turing-machines, finite-automata, pushdown-automata

I never heard or read about the concepts of "Minimizing Push Down Automata or Turing Machines"?
why we are not concerned about minimizing them, in general?

Comment: Since it's too hard (indeed, uncomputable)! NFA minimization is discussed in some papers, though.